# How to check if a key value pair is matching in one collection and update the value in the key present in another mongodb collection using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mapping

Collection 1:

```
username:"abc123"
```

Collection 2:

```
username:"abc123"
_id:ObjectId("5e78c5794f1f2d69b2a08139")
```

If "username" matches in both Collection 1 and 2, I should be able to copy the "_id" from Collection 2 and insert new key and value as "agent:

```
ObjectId("5e78c5794f1f2d69b2a08139"
```

Comment: In which collection you want to insert the new key? collection 1 or 2?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Want to insert the new key in Collection 1

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation can do this.

Run aggregate on Collection 2:

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation) to match with Collection 1
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#unwind-aggregation) the lookup result, which should eliminate any that didn't find a match
- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html#addfields-aggregation) to add the agent field to the looked up document
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html#replaceroot-aggregation) makes the root of each document the one retrieved from Collection 1, which now contains an agent
- [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#merge-aggregation) to combine the documents in the pipeline with Collection 1

```
db.getCollection("Collection 2").aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
               from: "Collection 1",
               localField: "username",
               foreignField: "username",
               as: "lookedup"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$lookedup"},
    {$addFields: {
            "lookedup.agent": "$_id"
    }},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$lookedup"}},
    {$merge: "Collection 1"}
])
```